# Unity Applications for different VR/AR devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, oculusquest, magic-leap

## Background

I have developed an application using Unity 2021.3.14 and MRTK 2.8 for the Hololens 2 to visualize data. Now I would like to use the application with other VR/AR devices.

## Question

My first attempt is currently to upgrade to a new version of Unity and MRTK V3.

I want to start with the Magic Leap 2 and the Meta Quest 3, both of which have completely different SDKs.
My question is, how easy is it to support these different devices through MRTK? Do I have to load the SDKs of each device via the Asset Store or is it done via OpenXR in Unity and do I have to pay special attention to any settings? Or are there other experiences from similar projects that recommend alternatives to MRTK?

Thanks for any tips or ideas.